# Pasting an Excel range using VBA to PPT - pasted positions change

Tags: vba, excel, position

I am using VBA to copy a range from Excel and paste this to a PowerPoint slide. I add the top, left, and width coordinates to position the slide.  The range I am pasting does not change - what is happening is some days the left position changes.  Today, it was the top position.  I am not changing the coordinates.  I've Googled this issue and not have found a solution.  Code is below.

```
'Oct17
'Open a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(10)

'Copy Range from Excel
   Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Oct17").Range("A1:N68")
   Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Oct17").Range("L73:N73")

'Copy Excel Range
  rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
PowerPointApp.WindowState = 2
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile  0 = ppPasteDefault
Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

'Set position:
myShape.Left = 20        '15 / 0 / 20
myShape.Top = 70         '91
myShape.Width = 675
'myShape.Height = 400

'Copy Excel Range
  rng2.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
PowerPointApp.WindowState = 2
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile  0 = ppPasteDefault
Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

'Set position:
myShape.Left = 494
myShape.Top = 527
myShape.Width = 300
'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
'PowerPointApp.Visible = msoTrue
'PowerPointApp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
```

Comment: Is the position changing for rng1, rng2 or both?

Comment: just for range 1

Comment: I have some additional information - it looks like this occurs whenever I move the slides.....putting them in current month order.....i.e. first slide is nov, then dec, etc.  Creating them in chronological order though.  So when I took out the moves - the slide in question creates as it should.  No reposition needed.  So this only happens on the last slide (current month) moved to the first position...... the code to accomplish this is below

Comment: 'Move the sheets in order by the current month
myPresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo toPos:=12 'jan
myPresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo toPos:=12 'feb
myPresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo toPos:=12 'mar
myPresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo toPos:=12 'apr
myPresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo toPos:=12 'may
myPresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo toPos:=12 'jun
myPresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo toPos:=12 'jul
myPresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo toPos:=12 'aug
myPresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo toPos:=12 'sep
myPresentation.Slides(1).MoveTo toPos:=12 'oct

Comment: I am no longer having any positioning issues with the left parameter.  It only happens with the top position.  I am having occurrences where I ran the code - the top position is half way the page now.  I change the top position and it's way at the top.  If I now put the top position at the original location from the first run - it's now where it should be - whereas the first time it ran - it was down the page.  This only happens with the first sorted slide in the deck (I sort so that the most current month is first and then the rest for the year).  This is maddening!  ;-(

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in Excel driving me mad and the best I could determine was that having zoom not at 100% or changing zoom levels caused the position in .top and .left to change unprompted.  Even changing between worksheets and workbooks caused the positions to shift.